# JButton and JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I am having a problem with my `JButton` and `JComboBox`.

When I click on my `JButton` it does nothing.

I want a `JOptionPane` message to pop up after clicked.

```
selectionBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {
    "Insert", "Delete", "Find", "Update"
}));
selectionBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
selectionBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        selection = selectionBox.getSelectedIndex();
        switch (selection) {
            case 0:
                selection = 0;
        }
    }
});
processButton.setText("Process Request");
processButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (selection == 0) {
            insertStudent();
        }
    }
});
public void insertStudent() {
    int id;
    String name;
    String major;
    id = Integer.parseInt(idTextField.getText());
    name = nameTextField.getText();
    major = majorTextField.getText();
    student.getID(id);
    student.getName(name);
    student.getMajor(major);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "test");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that selection variable is 0? Use insertStudent(); method without if statment and check if JOptionPane will be shown.

Comment: `switch(selection){ case 0: selection = 0; }` is unnecessary... just saying.

Comment: put a System.out.println at the end of each of your action listeners to print the value of selection.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to remove the ActionListener on your combobox. Instead, access the *currently selected value* inside of your JButton's action listener and make sure you always get some feedback:

```
processButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch(selectionBox.getSelectedIndex()) {
            case 0:
              insertStudent();
              break;
            default:
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not yet implemented");
              break;
        }
    }
});
```